# Searching partial strings through tuple within a tuple

Tags: python

Ok, I need a little help because I'm extremely confused with what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to search a tuple within a tuple for partial string matches. However I can't seem to figure out how to do it properly.

This is what I have so far.

```
search = input("Enter name to search for: ")
for i in range(len(members)):
  if search in members[i]:
    print("Something")
```

However it always comes back false. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to get another counter to search through the inner tuple?

Comment: What does `members` look like?

Comment: `search in members[i]` looks for exact string if present in the tuple. I guess that is the reason for the result.

Comment: show your nested tuple

Comment: It is useless to use len to iterate on an iterable, why do people always use len?

Comment: without seeing members, your question is unanswerable

Comment: I agree, we need to see "members"

Comment: My apologies "members" looks something like this.

    members = ((John Doe, W456D, Boston), (Jane Doe, D46DF, New York))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am relatively new to python too. is it a type mismatch?

```
members = (('fred','bob', 'allen', 'bill'),('ann', 'brenda', 'jill'))
>>> "bren" in members
False
>>> "bren" in str(members)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work, when I try:

```
members = ['hello','hellooo']
search = 'ell'

for i in range(len(members)):
    if search in members[i]:
        print("Something")
```

The result is:

```
Something
Something
```

It might be an issue with what your `members` is as Alex Thornton pointed out above.

Comment: An answer to say that someone else's comment was correct and that the code works?

Comment: I don't have the required 50 reputation needed to "add a comment " to the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote you to begin with, but I'll upvote you since I agree with your answer.

Comment: Gotcha, made a small edit, thanks for the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

```
members = (('foo', 'bar'), ('foo', 'baz'))

search = raw_input("Enter name to search for: ")

for tuple in members:
  for item in tuple:
    if search in item:
      print("Something")
```

This code works.
Test:

```
$ python foo.py
Enter name to search for: foo
Something
Something
```

Comment: where are your tuples?

Comment: the question has not been clarified and should be closed as without seeing what members actually is, it is not possible to answer

Comment: input is being used as the OP is most likely using python 3

Comment: Oh yes, I remember you explaining that in python3, raw_input became input and the "old" input got demised